# Can't see swipe tab tabs

Tags: android, tabs, toolbar, swipe

Hi I make an swipe tab app, it works whena i swipe the screen , but i don't see the tabs part. How can i resolve it?
Can you help me.
Thanks

Here is my XML layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.hakobm.tabdemo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <include
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            layout="@layout/toolbar_layout"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/tablayout"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"
        />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/viewpager">

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my MainActivity file

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Toolbar toolbar;
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    ViewPagerAdapter viewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        tabLayout= (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
        viewPager= (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


        viewPagerAdapter=new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Home(),"Home");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Top(),"Top");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new Buttom(),"Buttom");
        viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    }
}
```

And this is my adapters part:

```
public class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private ArrayList<Fragment> fragments= new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragments(Fragment fragments, String titles){

        this.fragments.add(fragments);
        this.tabTitles.add(titles);

    }

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return fragments.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragments.size();
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabTitles.get(position);
       // return "Tab" + position;
    }
}
```

i can't see the reason why my tabs don't available.
I added compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1' into my grandle.app file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

Add an id to the **appbarlayout** like this:

```
android:id="@+id/appbar"
```

And add this to the **tabs**:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/appbar"
```